# Using a promise with a 'require' to dynamically load module

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

I am using mongoose and am trying to dynamically load a schema / model using 'require' but I get unusual behaviour.  More specifically, the 'require' executes after the promise chain has completed which is not what I would have expected.  Rather, I would have expected the 'require' which is synchronous (from what I understand) to complete, and then the promise.resolve to be invoked in sequence which would maintain the promise chain.

(note: I do not think mongoose is involved in this issue but is used in this example to illustrate the issue)

My code (simplified to illustrate the problem) is listed below:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function connect(){
  console.log('Connecting');
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongodb');
    mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
        resolve();
    });
  });
}

function configure(fileName){
  console.log('Configuring filename: %s', fileName);
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    console.log('Requiring filename: %s', fileName);
    require(filename);
    console.log('Required filename: %s', fileName);
    resolve();
  });
}

function findAll(modelName){
  console.log('Finding');
  mongoose.model(modelName).find(function(err, data) {
    console.log('Model: %s, found items: %s', modelName, data);
  });
}

var modelName = 'users';
var modelFile = './' + modelName;
connect()
  .then(function(){
    configure(modelFile);
  })
  .then(function(){
    findAll(modelName);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log('Mainline promise error: %s', err.stack);
    process.exit(0);
  });
```

The module ('users.js') that contains the schema and model creation (which is loaded in the 'require') is illustrated below.  Note that as the 'require' does not complete, I assume this module is not loaded, but for completeness I have included it:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

console.log('users schema starting');
var schema = new Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  middlename: String
});

var users = mongoose.model('users', schema);
console.log('users schema defined');

module.exports = users;
```

The console messages below illustrate that the 'require' seems to execute out of sequence (ie. the 'require' starts, the subsequent promise is resolved, but the 'require' does not complete synchronously).  Hence when the 'find' takes place, the schema/model is not available:

```
Connecting
Configuring filename: ./users
Requiring filename: ./users
Finding
Mainline promise error: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "users".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model ({user-dir}node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:349:13)
    at findAll ({user-dir}main.js:28:14)
    at {user-dir}main.js:40:9
    at tryCatcher ({user-dir}node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler ({user-dir}node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:507:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt ({user-dir}node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:581:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises ({user-dir}node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:697:14)
    at Async._drainQueue ({user-dir}node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues ({user-dir}node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] ({user-dir}node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Any insights regarding a solution or alternate approach is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to return the promises created in your `then`s. Right now you're registering two callbacks for when `connect` resolves, but never registering any callbacks for the `configure` and `findAll` promises.

```
connect()
.then(function(){ // called when connect resolves
  configure(modelFile); // creates a new promise
})
.then(function(){ // called when connect resolves and the previous function returns
  findAll(modelName);
})
```

If you change that to something like:

```
connect()
.then(function(){
  return configure(modelFile);
})
.then(function(){ // called when the promise from the previous function resolves
  return findAll(modelName);
})
```

You should see the desired behavior.